# Searching for different string length in variable

Tags: python

For the variable phoneNumber, it asks for the whole phone number; something like this: 029 123456. However, I only need the first area code. But there can also be area codes like this: 01845 123456 with a different amount of characters as the area code. How would I get it so it just stores the area code in the variable?

Here's a small sample of the [full CSV file](http://www.101computing.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/phonecodes.csv):

```
PhoneCode,Area,Example,Latitude,Longitude
113,Leeds,(0113) xxx xxxx,53.801279,-1.548567
114,Sheffield,(0114) xxx xxxx,53.381129,-1.470085
115,Nottingham,(0115) xxx xxxx,52.95477,-1.158086
116,Leicester,(0116) xxx xxxx,52.636878,-1.139759
117,Bristol,(0117) xxx xxxx,51.454513,-2.58791
118,Reading,(0118) xxx xxxx,51.452884,-0.973906
1200,Clitheroe,(01200) xxxxxx,53.871098,-2.393083
1202,Bournemouth,(01202) xxxxxx,50.719164,-1.880769
1204,Bolton,(01204) xxxxxx,53.584441,-2.428619
```

and here's the code I have so far:

```
phoneNumber = input("Enter your phone number (UK landline only):")

file = open("phonecodes.csv","r")

#Complete the code here
for line in file:
  data = line.split(",")
  areaCode = data[0]
  if phoneNumber == "0" + areaCode:
    print data[1]

file.close()
```

Comment: They are all in separate columns so just extract the column you want, use the csv module

Comment: Two comments: 1) Don't use `file` as a variable name; using the builtins as variable names is a bad idea. 2) The `f = open(path) ... f.close()` design is an antipattern; better to use `with open(path) as f: ...`, which ensures the file will always be closed.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Thanks but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to just store the area code from phoneNumber, instead of the whole number. So instead of storing 029 123456, it just stores 029.

Comment: @alexwlchan Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Are you talking about the phone number the user inputs or what exactly as all the data in the csv is in separate columns?

Comment: what about using `if phoneNumber.startswith("0"+areaCode):` ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, the phone number the user inputs.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger No thanks, I have the for loop working, it's just the variable phoneNumber which needs to just store the area code and not the whole number. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Then either take the area coed separately or get the user to add a space and use area, `num = input().split()`

Comment: @ConorYoungs Did you even tried it before refusing to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either get the user to enter the area code then the number separately or get them to enter the area code followed by a space then the number and split:

Separately:

```
area = raw_input("Enter your area code: ")
num = raw_input("Enter you phone number: ")


import csv

r = csv.reader(open("phonecodes.csv"))
for ph_cde, ar_cde, ex, lat, lon in r:
    if "0" + ph_cde ==  area:
       ........
```

Splitting:

```
area, num = raw_input("Enter your phone number (UK landline only) in format 

AREA NUM:").split()


import csv

r = csv.reader(open("phonecodes.csv"))
for ph_cde, ar_cde, ex, lat, lon in r:
   if "0" + ph_cde ==  area:
        .........
```

You data is comma separated so the csv module will split into columns for you. I also used raw_input as your print statement suggests you are using python2 not python3.